# SSIS - read data from sheet and pass each row to a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need to read data from excel sheet and pass each row as parameters to stored procedure.
i added Ole db Source to get data from Excel. but what then?

Any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a connection manager for the SQL database that contains the stored procedure.

Feed the resultset from the Excel `OleDB Data Source` into an `OleDB Command`, and in the editor for the command:

- **Connection Managers** tab - choose your new SQL connection manager
- **Component Properties** tab - set "SQLCommand" to `EXEC your_stored_proc ?, ?, ?` with a question mark for each parameter you want to pass to the stored procedure.
- **Column Mappings** tab - map your input fields onto the ? placeholders.